Unable to mock a RestClient bean when testing a class that uses this bean
So I have two classes : A RestClient class and another MetadataService class which uses the restClient bean.
This is the RestClient class
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig {
  //actual class is more complex than this as we are authenticating with kerberos and there's
  //code that generates kerberos token and injects it into the rest client builder 
  @Bean("customRestClient")
  public RestClient restClient(RestClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder.build();
  }
}
 


Below is the service class
@Component
public class MetadataService {
  @Autowired 
  @Qualifier("customRestClient")
  RestClient customRestClient;
  
  public void makeCall() {
     try {
         final String response = customRestClient.method(HTTPMethod.POST).uri("http://example.com")
                                      .headers(getHeaders()).body(//some body here).retrieve()
                                      .toEntity(String.class);
         log.info(response);
     }
  }
}



Now I want to write a test class for MetadataService.
Things I have tried :

Using @Mock annotation on the restClient bean but that lead to exceptions (more below)
Using @RestClientTest on the class albeit there's a lot of confusion on how I should use this.

Here is my test class which I have written so far (what I have referenced in #1)
public class MetadataServiceTest {

@Mock
RestClient customRestClient;

@InjectMock
MetadataService metadataService;

@Test
public void testMakeCall() {

when(customRestClient.method(HTTPMethod.POST).uri("http://example.com")
     .headers(any()).body(any()).retrieve()
     .toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(response); 

metadataService.makeCall();
}

}

This leads to exceptions like this one:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$RequestBodyUriSpec(String, Object[])" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.client.RestClient.method(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod)" is null

I don't see the whole class including your imports but you missed this annotation on the class level:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

As far as I remember in modern versions of Mockito it has become very picky about using an any() matcher when a null value is passed as a parameter, it won't actually match. So that headers() call in there which receives the return value from getHeaders() seems suspicious to me. What does getHeaders() return?

@RuslanZinovyev tried that quickly; same error

@Gimby it returns a Map<> of headers. However, I expect Mockito to throw errors specifically in regards to the matchers if that is a problem. But, the error says the test run is failing at .method(HTTPMethod.POST) because that is returning null.

@kataraaaa method(POST) is returning null. You have not stubbed a return value, so the default value for the type is returned (and that is null for objects).

You are missing the @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) annotation to have your test run with Mockito support. Without the annotation, @Mock and friends are completely ignored.
Additionally, you would only be stubbing the first level of calls on customRestClient. Without existing stubs, a Mockito mock object will return the default value for any given type (0 for numeric types, false for booleans, empty collections, null for objects and strings). Writing something like when(mock.method()).thenReturn(result) still must call the method method on the mock instance. There's no way around it and Mockito cannot change the behavior of the Java language.
This means that a line such as
when(customRestClient.method(HTTPMethod.POST).uri("http://example.com")
     .headers(any()).body(any()).retrieve()
     .toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(response); 

will first call customRestClient.method(HTTPMethod.POST), then call uri("http://example") on its result. Since customRestClient.method is not stubbed, it returns the default value (i.e. null). You cannot call a method on a null reference and consequently, you encounter a NullPointerException. It just so happens that when ignores the value passed in and does not do anything with the return value from the method call; only the return type is inferred from the expression.
You would have to stub each level of calls. First stub customRestClient.method to return a mock object. Then stub the uri call on this mock object to return another mock object. Stub headers on that object and so on.
Fortunately, Mockito provides a helpful shortcut: @Mock(Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS). This sets up the mock object to return another mock object from each of its methods. Subsequently, customRestClient.method(HTTPMethod.POST) in your when call returns a mock and calling uri("http://example.com") on this mock will return another mock, etc. Eventually, the toEntity call on the final mock object returned from your call chain is stubbed to return response.
Simply add it as attribute on the annotation:
@Mock(RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
RestClient customRestClient;

Just be aware of the JavaDoc of RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS:

WARNING: This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).
Good quote I've seen one day on the web: every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies.


Thank you for this answer! I was stuck for a while there but your suggestion about deep stubs got me thinking - it wasn't quite the thing that worked but it got me started in the right direction. And you're absolutely right about mocking every call starting from method(), uri() etc etc, which is what I applied. :)

@kataraaaa what didn't work when using deep stubs?

it was returning its own response from the code (hence, deep stub i guess) and I wanted simple mocking and return of my own defined response using when().

@kataraaaa you should still be able to stub the final call in your chain. In fact, you should be able to simply take the when(…) call from your question as is if you add RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS to your annotation. The behavior (and returned value) is the same as with the manual stubs in your answer.

damn, It returned a null value for me that way. I am gonna check out what went wrong with my implementation.

In your case, it's better to stick with the @RestClientTest annotation.
@RestClientTest is used to test the interaction of your service with an external REST API without hitting the actual endpoints. This way, you can mock the endpoint responses and focus on testing your service logic.
You can check this tutorial if you don't know how to handle it, it's pretty straightforward: https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot
If you insist on your approach which doesn't look right to me you can use deep stubbing as was mentioned above, since RestClient is using builder pattern, but this approach is not the best choice from my perspective.

You are right. I ended up using simple mock classes for the stubs but this would have been the way to go.

I am posting an answer to my own question because I have figured out what works for me for the particular thing, and the answer by knittl got me thinking about the right things.
So this is what I want to test
when(customRestClient.method(HTTPMethod.POST).uri("http://example.com")
 .headers(any()).body(any()).retrieve()
 .toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(response); 

3 things:

method(), uri(), and headers() returns a RequestBodyUriSpec object
retrieve() returns a ResponseSpec object
The code to make the POST call is a chained method, and it also resembles builder pattern.

Hence, we have to create mock objects of RequestBodyUriSpec and ResponseSpec and use these for the stubs.
I couldn't use RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS as it would have returned a different mock each time for the response object, but I have a particular response body which needs to be returned from the mocked call.
@Mock
RestClient customRestClient //don't need deep stub as we will be stubbing the 
                            //builder pattern   

RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec = mock(RestClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);
ResponseSpec responseSpec = mock(RestClient.ResponseSpec.class);
when(customRestClient.method(HTTPMethod.POST)).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
when(requestBodyUriSpec.headers(any())).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
when(requestBodyUriSpec.body(any())).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
when(requestBodyUriSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
when(requestBodyUriSpec.toEntity(anyString)).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("response", HttpStatus.OK)); // alternatively: Use any(ParameterizedReference.class) if you are using that 

REFERENCE: Stubbing the builder pattern in Mockito
